# Ignoring some tuples in a loop

Tags: python

I am producing some animation frames in tuples, which may contain (0,0) value, which I would like omit while producing frames with moviepy. The `xy` contains the following in a loop. The first and second iteration contains (0,0) and the rest contains floats. I would like ignore those iteration that possesses (0,0). Can it be done with moviepy's make_frame(t) def? I need some suggestions.

```
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(82.5, 82.5)
(82.5, 82.5)
(108.28125, 108.28125)
(108.28125, 108.28125)
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\vhosts\VIDEO_TWO_CLONE\vapory-examples-master\scene9.py", line 151, in <module>
    clip = VideoClip(make_frame, duration=5)
  File "C:\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 103, in __init__
    self.size = self.get_frame(0).shape[:2][::-1]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
Process terminated with an exit code of 1
```

Here is the def of the make_frame(t):

```
def make_frame(t):

    # PREPARE A DRAWING SURFACE
    surface = gizeh.Surface(width=W, height=H, bg_color=(0,0,0)) # in pixels

    p = PointAnimation((0,0), (110,110), tween=['easeOutElastic', 1, 0.2])

    xy = p.make_frame(t, 0.2, 1, 4, 5)

    if str(xy) == '(0,0)':
        circle = gizeh.circle(r=30, xy=xy, fill=(1,1,0))
        circle.draw(surface) # draw the circle on the surface
        return surface.get_npimage()


clip = VideoClip(make_frame, duration=5)
clip.write_gif("circle.gif", fps=25, fuzz=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have `if str(xy) == '(0,0)'`, when in fact this should be `if str(xy) == '(0, 0)'` (note the space inside the tuple; this is how tuples are converted to strings in Python). However, an even better way to do this is `if xy == (0,0)` (the space doesn't matter here because there's no conversion to string).

Comment: you missed the quotes in `if str(xy) == (0, 0) `